# Populating a from value from include (.php) file

Tags: php, forms, variables

I have a external php file called login.php

```
<?php

$valid_passwords = array ("admin" => "admin");
$valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords);

$user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

$validated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);

if (!$validated) {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Regency Plus Trading Platform"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  die ("Sorry... You are not authorized...");
}
// If arrives here, is a valid user.
echo "<p>Welcome $user.</p>";

?>
```

My index.php file contain a form and one hidden text field.
How can I populate the text field from $user value?

Thanks.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="foobar" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($user); ?>" />`

Answer (score 1):

When you include a file in PHP, the variables defined in the included file could be used in the file

```
<?php
include "login.php"; // $user is defined in this file
?>
<form ....>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user ?>">
</form>
```